# Calculate Total Ending Quantity by using previous and next row value (LAG & LEAD) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, partitioning

Calculate Total Ending Quantity by using previous and next row value (LAG & LEAD) in SQL Server. Here is the input data.

Input Data

```
Date         Account    Type    Quantity
12/28/2007         A    2N         719
3/28/2008          A    2N         806
6/27/2008          A    2N         622
9/26/2008          A    2N         748
12/26/2008         A    2N         757
```

Expected Output Data/ Desired Result

```
"Date"  "Account" "Type"    "Quantity" "Beginning Qty" "Net Change" "Zero Beginning Qty" "End Qty"
12/28/2007  A        2N      719        n/a             n/a          n/a    0
3/28/2008   A        2N      806        719             87            0    87
6/27/2008   A        2N      622        806            -184           87  -96
9/26/2008   A        2N      748        622             126          -96   29
12/26/2008  A        2N      757        748              9            29   38




select      Date, Account, Type, Quantity
    ,  LAG(Quantity, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Date) as  [Beginning Qty]
    ,  Quantity- LAG(Quantity,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS [Net_Change_Qty]
    , (Quantity- LAG(Sec_Share_Qty,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) + LEAD(Quantity, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY Date)) as [Zero_Qty_Beginning]
    ,[Net_Change_Qty] + [Zero_Qty_Beginning] as [End Qty]
from        Table
order by    [Date]
```

Existing Query works for Beginning & Net Change columns. however, for column "Zero Beginning Qty" this code is not giving expected output.

Current Incorrect Results

```
Date    Account Type    Quantity    Beginning Quantity  Net Change  Zero Beginning Qty  End Quantity
12/28/2007  A   2N      719      0      719 1525    NULL
3/28/2008   A   2N      806    719       87 710     NULL
6/27/2008   A   2N      622    806     -184 564     NULL
9/26/2008   A   2N      748    622      126 883     NULL
12/26/2008  A   2N      757    748        9 765     NULL
```

Comment: Is there a question hidden in there? Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML (Create table and insert into statements), and show desired results vs your current results.

Comment: What does "not working" mean"  What results do you want?

Answer (score 0):

You try to nest analytical functions, which is not allowed.

Based on your expected result all your calculations seem to be based on two values: the quantity in the previous row and the 1st row.

```
with cte as
 (
   select      Date, Account, Type, Quantity
    ,  LAG(Quantity, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS LagQty -- previous row
    ,  first_value(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS firstQty -- first row
   from        Tab
 )
select Date, Account, Type, Quantity
  ,LagQty as [Beginning Qty]
  ,Quantity - LagQty AS [Net_Change_Qty]
  ,LagQty - firstQty AS [Zero_Qty_Beginning]
  ,Quantity - firstQty AS [End_Qty]
from cte
order by    [Date]
```